# how can i active app by using phone balance?

Tags: java, android

I have a question about android codes, I want to understand some developers use some codes to buy or active his app, for example, I have Dictionary and it is not free, but I want user full active dictionary by using a balance of phone number, when the user send me a balance I send to user number to active, please I want understanding that it how?!

Comment: It looks like you have some reading to do ... I don't even understand your question. I don't think people on the community can help on this one.

Comment: @Helpha My question is how can Some developers active app by using phone balance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking about how to bill an in-app purchase to a user's cellular provider.

This is not possible in any general fashion. Android runs on a wide variety of devices, many of which aren't even cell phones. If you want to support in-app purchases, you should probably use [Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api).